# CDK creating additional stack for ELB resources

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk

I'm using CDK to create a stack with some ELB resources. Everything seems to be working correctly, but I end up with two CloudFormation stacks. One named `demo` and another that has a randomly generated name like `awseb-e-jkmuguqm3e-stack`.

The `demo` stack has the ElasticBeanstalk Application and Environment, but the other stack has a bunch of load balancer resources, including an AutoScalingGroup, LaunchConfiguration, ScalingPolicy, etc, that I assume are created as part of the ELB stuff, but I would think they'd end up in the same stack?

*disclaimer: this might be entirely expected behavior, as everything works, but being new to CDK I figured someone might know why i get an extra stack here, and maybe there is something I can do to prevent it*

I've defined an AppStack (cdk-app/index.ts):

```
export class AppStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);


    const stackName = _.get(props, ['stackName'], '');

    const app = new elasticBeanstalk.CfnApplication(this, `${stackName}EbsApplication`, {
      applicationName: `${_.toLower(stackName)}-ebs-app`
    });

    const ebsInstanceRole = new iam.Role(
      this,
      `${stackName}EBSInstanceRole`,
      {
        roleName: `${_.toLower(stackName)}-ebs-role`,
        assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com'),
      }
    );

    // create an instance profile the that instances in our EBS environment will use
    const ebsInstanceProfile = new iam.CfnInstanceProfile(
      this,
      `${stackName}InstanceProfile`,
      {
        instanceProfileName: `${_.toLower(stackName)}-ebs-instance-profile`,
        roles: [
          ebsInstanceRole.roleName,
        ],
      }
    );

    const env = new elasticBeanstalk.CfnEnvironment(this, 'Environment', {
      environmentName: `${_.toLower(stackName)}-ebs-env`,
      applicationName: `${_.toLower(stackName)}-ebs-app`,
      solutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.0.2 running Node.js 12',
      optionSettings: [
        {
          namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
          optionName: 'IamInstanceProfile',
          value: ebsInstanceProfile.instanceProfileName,

        }
      ]
    });
  }
}

export default AppStack;
```

I use the stack (index.ts):

```
import AppStack from "./cdk-app";

const app = new cdk.App();

const appStack = new AppStack(app, 'demoAppStack', { stackName: 'demo' });

app.synth();
```

Comment: cant see where you create a stack. the code just creates resources with a prefix from a variable called stackName

Comment: @Marc sorry, this code all lives within the constructor for a stack, I'll update the example

Comment: Without knowing much about the stack code itself I want to bring up two things to clarify here. 1. You have exported the stack twice `export class AppStack extends cdk.Stack` and `export default AppStack;` 2. How are you importing the stack when you are using it just before `app.synth();`?

Comment: @dmahapatro im importing it using the default export, ie `import App stack from '../AppStack'`, I'll update example code. It is exporting twice but I don't think that should matter (the named export doesn't get used). Thank you for looking it over.

Comment: export default AppStack; makes no sense here.

Comment: @Marc isn't `export default AppStack` what enabled `import Appstack from...` to work? Else I would have to do `import { AppStack } from ...` if I was targeting the named export...

Comment: Maybe you are right. But that’s the only thing I ve seen is different from my code. But then I don’t have a clue why two stacks get created

Comment: @Marc i will remove one of the exports and see if it changes anything, are you able to do the same in your code without getting a second stack?

Comment: Hello @DonaldP. I'm currently working with CDK/Beanstalk, and am having the exact issue you reported here. I know it's 6 months late, but did you manage to solve it? As it's working I'm not too concerned, but if there's a clean way to have a single stack, I wouldn't mind using it. Cheers.

Comment: @Elegie I have not :/

Comment: This is a normal behavior for Elastic Beanstalk. In the past, I created a CloudFormation Template to deploy Beanstalk application, and it will automatically spin off another stack for the whole deployment. And For CDK, ultimately utilize CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just how Elastic Beanstalk works. It creates a nested stack for you (i.e., `awseb-e-jkmuguqm3e-stack` in your case). If you want to avoid it, I think you'd need to stop using Elastic Beanstalk.

Also worth noting what you are seeing is not CDK-specific. You'll also see the additional 'random' stack created when defining an EB stack using Cloudformation and when creating an EB environment via the AWS console.